# Calling facts in query

Tags: prolog

This is my code:

```
sentence([['o'],['m','e','n','i','n','o'],['a','l','e','g','r','e']]).

lastWord(X,[X]).
lastWord(X,[_|Z]) :- lastWord(X,Z).
```

If I try `lastWord(X,[1,2,3]).` or even `lastWord(X,[['o'],['m','e','n','i','n','o'],['a','l','e','g','r','e']]).` I get what I want (which is, of course, the last element of the list (in the examples, `3` and `['a','l','e','g','r','e']`.

But if I try `lastWord(X, sentence).` or `lastWord(X, sentence(Y)).` I get `false`.

How can I "call" the defined list (in this case, 'sentence') in lastWord?

Answer (score 2):

Prolog is not a functional language. Thus, in goals such as `lastWord(X, sentence)` or `lastWord(X, sentence(Y))` is not going to replace `sentence` or  `sentence(Y)` by the argument of the `sentence/1` predicate. Try instead:

```
?- sentence(List), lastWord(Last, List).
List = [[o], [m, e, n, i, n, o], [a, l, e, g, r, e]],
Last = [a, l, e, g, r, e] ;
false.
```

Note there's a spurious choice point left for the query. You can eliminate it by rewriting the definition of the predicate `lastWord/2`. A similar predicate, usually named `last/2`, is often available from libraries:

```
last([Head| Tail], Last) :-
    last(Tail, Head, Last).

last([], Last, Last).
last([Head| Tail], _, Last) :-
    last(Tail, Head, Last).
```

Note the different argument order (Prolog coding guidelines suggest to have input arguments preceding output arguments). Using this predicate instead:

```
?- sentence(List), last(List, Last).
List = [[o], [m, e, n, i, n, o], [a, l, e, g, r, e]],
Last = [a, l, e, g, r, e].
```